# CMake: Referencing a sibling native Android Library module from App code

Tags: cmake, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries, static-libraries, android-library

I have an Android Studio project with a general layout as follows:

```
Project/
 |
 +-- app/
 |  |
 |  +-- src/main/cpp/
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- native-lib.cpp
 |  |  +-- CMakeLists.txt
 |  |
 |  +-- build.gradle
 |  +-- CMakeLists.txt
 |  |
 +-- sibling-lib/
 |  |
 |  +-- src/main/cpp/
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- partA/CMakeLists.txt
 |  |  +-- partB/CMakeLists.txt
 |  |  +-- partC/CMakeLists.txt
 |  |
 |  +-- build.gradle
 |  +-- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 +-- build.gradle
 +-- settings.gradle
```

`sibling-lib` is a third-party library comprised of multiple parts, each with separate sources and common headers, each of which is compiled into either a static or shared library, using the associated CMake file, and included as a subdirectory by the top-level library CMake file. Most of those parts are dependent on other parts.

The goal is to compile and link the parts of `sibling-lib` into library files within an Android Library (.aar) and use those libraries from the native files within the main app (e.g. `native-lib.cpp`). I have been able to compile each of the parts as a static library, with the final part linked together as a shared library (using target_link_libraries() on that part), and then load the library from the app's Java code. However, when I try to call any of `sibling-lib`'s functions, I receive reference errors when compiling.

How should I configure the CMake and gradle files (for both the app and library) to properly compile and set up my project? Is there, however, a better way to configure the project to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Did you check that your `sibling-lib` library has the symbols? Did you try to consume the library without using a `.aar`?